# How to tell Qt-Creator using debug or release third-party libs?

Tags: qt-creator, ld

I use Qtcreator as IDE and the .pro file for the configuration on a Linux machine.

My goal is to compile my software using debug libs from third party libs (and this is why I don't use `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`)

Here is the part of the pro file concerning the libs:

```
CONFIG(debug, debug|release) {
    LIBS += -L/sw/Vtk/lib/vtk-5.10-deb
} else {
    LIBS += -L/sw/Vtk/lib/vtk-5.10
}

LIBS += -lvtkCommon -lvtkRendering
```

But this give me the following error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: warning: libvtksys.so.5.10, needed by /sw/Vtk/lib/vtk-5.10-deb/libvtkCommon.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

`libvtksys.so.5.10` exist in `/sw/Vtk/lib/vtk-5.10-deb` and I don't understand why `ld` can find `libvtkCommon.so` which is on the same folder?

And how to configure Qt Creator for builds debug using debug libs?

Answer (score 0):

Juste adding `QMAKE_RPATHDIR`correct the problem in my case:

```
QMAKE_RPATHDIR += /sw/Vtk/lib/vtk-5.10-deb
```

Source: [qt centre](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/40128-How-to-set-rpath-in-Qt-Project)